# Understanding Lemma 2.1 on pg.105 in AT.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, exact-sequence

The lemma and its proof are given below:

> [image]
>   [image]

**My questions are:**

1- In the second and third line of the proof, why is the case $i = j$ is not considered?

2- why we switch $i$ and $j$ in the second sum? and why this leads to that the second sum becomes the negative of the first?

Comment: I'd write out all the terms in a particular case, say $n=4$, to get this straight in my mind.

Comment: You should try to write the sum without the symbol $\sum$ and with few indices just to understand what is going on. But basically, the first $\partial$ remove the $i$-th index and the second, well, cannot remove it again.

Comment: And what about the $\vartriangle_{n} (X)$ .... how can I substitute for it @Roland

Comment: And what about the $\vartriangle_{n} (X)$ .... how can I substitute for it @LordSharktheUnknown

Answer (score 1):

You have to compute $\partial_{n-1}(\sigma \mid [v_0,\ldots,v_{i-1},v_{i+1},\ldots,v_n])$. Write $[v_0,\ldots,v_{i-1},v_{i+1},\ldots,v_n] =[w_0,\dots,w_{n-1}]$ with $w_j = v_j$ for $0< j < i$ and $w_j = v_{j+1}$ for $i \le j \le n-1$ shows that
$$\partial_{n-1}(\sigma \mid [v_0,\ldots,v_{i-1},v_{i+1},\ldots,v_n]) = \partial_{n-1}(\sigma \mid [w_0,\ldots,w_{n-1}]) = \sum_{j=0}^{n-1}(-1)^j\sigma \mid [w_0,\ldots,\hat w_j,\ldots,w_{n-1}])  \\ = \sum_{j=0}^{i-1}(-1)^j\sigma \mid [w_0,\ldots,\hat w_j,\ldots,w_{n-1}]) +  \sum_{j=i}^{n-1}(-1)^j\sigma \mid [w_0,\ldots,\hat w_j,\ldots,w_{n-1}]) \\ = \sum_{j=0}^{i-1}(-1)^j\sigma \mid [v_0,\ldots,\hat v_j,\ldots,\hat v_i,\ldots,v_n]) + \sum_{j=i}^{n-1}(-1)^j\sigma \mid [v_0,\ldots,\hat v_i,\ldots,\hat v_{j+1},\ldots,v_n]) \\ = \sum_{j=0}^{i-1}(-1)^j\sigma \mid [v_0,\ldots,\hat v_j,\ldots,\hat v_i,\ldots,v_n]) + \sum_{k=i+1}^{n}(-1)^{k-1}\sigma \mid [v_0,\ldots,\hat v_i,\ldots,\hat v_k,\ldots,v_n])$$
In the last line we replaced $j$ by $k-1$ so that $k = j+1$ and the summation goes from $k = i+1$ to $k=n-1+1 =n$. In the line before note that omitting $w_j$ for $j \ge i$ means omitting $v_{j+1}$.